# Telegram Bot | Golang | Failed to create invoice | Error REPLY_MARKUP_BUY_EMPTY

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I have been using [telego](https://github.com/SakoDroid/telego/) to create a telegram bot, Recently I got stuck creating a new invoice message for payments.

Where is my code

```golang
providerToken := "123:XXXX:123" 
err = bot.AddHandler("/pay", func(u *objs.Update) {
    kb := bot.CreateInlineKeyboard()
    kb.AddCallbackButtonHandler("Buy", "pay", 1, func(u *objs.Update) {
        _, err = bot.SendMessage(u.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "Payed", "", 0, false, false)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    })
    inv := bot.AdvancedMode().ACreateInvoice(
        u.Message.Chat.Id,
        "Test invoice",
        "description here",
        "custom_payload",
        providerToken,
        "USD",
        []objs.LabeledPrice{{Label: "USD", Amount: 200}},
        40,
        []int{10, 20},
        "start_param",
        "",
        "",
        0,
        0,
        0,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        kb,
    )
    _, err = inv.Send(u.Message.MessageId, false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}, "private")
```

When I call this handler I get the following errors

```
2023/03/28 13:30:15 Unable to send sendInvoice. received status code 400
Error code : 400, Description : Bad Request: REPLY_MARKUP_BUY_EMPTY
```

Despite I am passing `kb` to the invoice and it has a callback button (In the case is 1 button only), I am getting error that it is empty.

I tried doing something similar with the default [telegram package for go](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api) and things worked just fine.

I tried to dig in the source code to see if it is not setting the keyboard before sending the request to telegram api, Everything works fine till that point actually